# Testing Code That Has Time Delays

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit

Whilst refactoring an app I'm working on I moved a piece of code from the  business logic layer to a helper. The code in question is a fire and forget method that will execute a piece of code if it hasn't been cancelled after an amount of time.

The method looks like this:

```csharp
public async static void CancelAfter(int seconds, CancellationToken token, Action action)
{
    try
    {
        await Task.Delay(seconds * 1000, token);

        action.Invoke();
    }
    catch (TaskCanceledException)
    {
        //cancelled
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //log error
    }
}
```

If the token gets cancelled then the `TaskCancelledException` will throw, it not it will invoke the action which whatever class calling this helper will determine.

Now I call this code in a very important stage of my application when it loads and is trying to perform startup tasks. If for any reason the app fails to load (no internet, server is down) this code should be triggered. If my app loads successfully I want to forget about this code and  move forward, hence why I code to make it a `void` fire & forget method.

I have written a series of tests to ensure this method performs as I'd expect it to (it does) BUT they involve waiting for the amount of time I put into method (5 seconds if I input 5). This adds a nice amount of overhead to running my tests as I like to test various scenarios and have multiple `[TestCase]` inputs.

An example of a test would be:

```
[TestCase(1)]
[TestCase(5)]
[TestCase(15)]
[TestCase(60)]
public async Task TestCancelled(int seconds)
{
    var tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    var token = tokenSource.Token;

    var action = new Mock<Action>();
    action.Setup(m => m.Invoke()).Callback(OnSomething);

    DelayHelper.CancelAfter(seconds, token, OnSomething);

    tokenSource.Cancel();//In my test not cancelled method I would not call Cancel();

    await Task.Delay(seconds * 1000);

    action.Verify(m => m.Invoke(), Times.Never()); //Times.Once() when in the not cancelled test
}

void OnSomething()
{
    //do something
}
```

I would almost like to how if there is a way I can mock the delay, like using Shims (which I can't seem to get working in my .NET Core Test Project...). Or maybe I should rework the code and use dependency inversion. Looking at the time taken to run my tests and the theoretical time taken if I passed a larger number to the method makes me think I'm missing something.

Would you consider my current approach acceptable? what can I improve about my approach to writing this sort of code?

*The tests I wrote do pass and the code appears to work, the issue being that i've introduced an overhead for the execution of my tests which I'd like to try and avoid*

Comment: Just a side not, maybe you should rename `seconds` to `milliseconds` because if one is reading this code and seeing `seconds * 1000` one would think to never ever call it with e.g `60` like one of your test-setups suggest.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Your question is not a real code review, since it doesn't contain the full real code that you want reviewed, and that makes it off topic. Please add the code, otherwise the question will be closed.

Comment: @Donald.McLean I have provided the exact code of my helper class in the first example (omitting the logging that is specific to my application) and the unit test code which is what I was asking to code review. Its all there...

Comment: Is all the code working expected?

Comment: I'm not the one who created the site standards for what constitutes a valid question. I'm just telling you that this isn't a site for asking about "best practices" and any posted code that is incomplete ("// do something") is going to get the question closed.

Comment: @pacmaninbw The code works exactly as i'd expect it to, I'm looking to improve how I can test that the code is working as I'd expect without introducing massive delays in test execution, which are the current downsides of the implementation

Comment: What @Donald.McLean is referring to are the comment `// Do Something` we are looking for all the code to be complete.

Comment: The code with the comment is my dummy action in the unit test. The method does not require any implementation in test, all that is required of it is that I verify whether it does or doesn't get called whilst running the test. That is actually what my code looks like that I copied over 

Answer (score 2):

Make your code return a Task.  Even if you don't await it in the program doesn't mean you can't await it in your test.  Also pass in a TimeSpan instead of int for seconds.

```
public async static Task CancelAfter(TimeSpan delay, CancellationToken token, Action action)
```

The Task.Delay takes a TimeSpan as an option.  Reading code using the TimeSpan Factories is way nicer.  TasTimeSpan.FromSeconds(seconds) That's clear what is going to happen and there is no math involved to convert from milliseconds to seconds or hours or whatever.

Now that it's returning a task you can await it in

```
public async Task TestCancelled(int seconds)
{
    var tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100));
    var token = tokenSource.Token;
    var action = new Mock<Action>();
    action.Setup(m => m.Invoke()).Callback(() => { });
    await DelayHelper.CancelAfter(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(seconds), token, action.Object);
    action.Verify(m => m.Invoke(), Times.Never()); //Times.Once() when in the not cancelled test
}
```

Also you have bug in your test.  You should be passing in the mock object instead of the dosomething.  But really don't even need the dosomething method.

I'm also using the TimeSpan overload for the CancellationToken so don't have to manually call cancel.  But you could restructure the code to still call Cancel if you wish.